# UITableView as a tableHeaderView for another UITableView

Tags: iphone, delegates, uitableview

I get stuck on the following: I want to use a single cell of a UITableView as a header view for another UITableView. The second table view is in turn an object that has been inherited from a different UITableView class, since it shares it's functionality completely. The only difference in fact is that the second UITableView has a header view (which should be the single celled UITableView).

The interface for the UITableView with the header looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ScheduleDetailsController.h"

@interface TodayDetailsViewController : ScheduleDetailsController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
   UITableView *headerView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *headerView;  

@end
```

And the implementation like:

```
#import "TodayDetailsViewController.h"

@implementation TodayDetailsViewController

@synthesize headerView;

- (void)loadView {
   [super loadView];

   self.headerView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
   self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   self.headerView.opaque = NO;
   self.headerView.delegate = self;
   self.headerView.dataSource = self;

   // This is a UITableView defined as a property in the parent class 
   self.scheduleDetailsTable.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
}

...

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   if (tableView == self.scheduleDetailsTable.tableHeaderView)
      return 1;
   else
      return [self.scheduleDetailsTable numberOfSections];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   if (tableView == self.scheduleDetailsTable.tableHeaderView)
      return 1;
   else
      return [self.scheduleDetailsTable numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if (tableView == self.scheduleDetailsTable.tableHeaderView) {

   ...

      return cell;
   } else
      return [self.scheduleDetailsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

@end
```

I get no errors when I compile and run this, but then I also don't see anything, i.e. the view stays empty. I have also tried it with replacing the header view by a UIView and then everything works like expected (i.e. the table view in the parent class is implemented correctly). I'm probably just missing something obvious, but I just can't figure it out at the moment. If someone could spot the error or could give some advice I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Not for nothing, but do you really need to create a whole <strike>UITableViewController and</strike> UITableView just to use a UITableViewCell as a header?  A UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView, after all.

This works, more or less, (had to make the labels not opaque myself; I guess the UITableView normally handles that):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITableViewController *testTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:NULL];

    tableViewCell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    tableViewCell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
    tableViewCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"123";
    tableViewCell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;

    testTableViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableViewCell;

    [tableViewCell release];

    // self.window is initilized and hooked up in MainMenu.xib
    self.window.rootViewController = testTableViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [testTableViewController release];

    return YES;
}
```

For that matter, if the above wont meet your needs why not just bump everything down in your table view by one section, and use the very top section as the "header":

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return ([super numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView] + 1);
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(section + 1)];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        // ***** Build and return your header cell *****
    } else {
        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:(indexPath.section + 1)];
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
    }
}
```

Repeat as necessary for all the other data source delegates.

Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, the single UITableViewCell option you gave seems the best option indeed. However, the only problem with this is that it doesn't seem possible to trigger some action (i.e. push a new view) when this single cell gets selected (or maybe there is?). Also, the second option you give is not really adequate for my case, since the top cell needs to be a normal cell and the bottom table view style needs to be grouped.

Comment: Just a thought to myself... Would it be a good idea to add a UIButton as a subview to the single UITableViewCell so as to be able to trigger some action?

Comment: @MJD Glad you solved your problem.  FWIW, it would probably be OK to put a button across the entire table view cell and track clicks that way.  If you wanted the hilight when you selected the cell to match a normal table view, you'd have to call [tableViewCell setSelected:YES animated:NO] yourself to match expected behavior.  (For some reason when you select a cell in a table view, the OS doesn't use the built in anamation...)

But, it does start to fell a little hack-y...  You're probably better off doing it your way if you need the two different styles...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved the problem by replacing the return statements of the delegate methods in my original posting from

```
return [self.scheduleDetailsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to

```
return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And similarly for the other delegate methods. Now everything works like expected. Thanks to **peterjb** for using this syntax in his response to my original question.

Comment: I'm trying to do something very similar to the EKEventViewController. But it won't compile because EKEventViewController doesn't have the delegate methods defined in it's interface. Any ideas?